# Misting/Fogging Nozzles as Rocket Injectors

Tags: rockets, design-alternative, injector

Misting and Fogging Nozzles are nozzles often used in irrigation and cooling. They basically use high pressure to break the liquid into tiny droplets achieving really great atomization. I think these kind of nozzles are also used in those hose heads where you change the output. It creates a pretty good example of how the rocket injector plate would work when using misting and fogging nozzles.

Now my question is why people aren’t using it. Why is it a bad idea? The only problem I see is that flow is pretty spread out instead of directional, but that is easy fix and it is designed to have a wide spread to cover a larger area. I think it has better atomization than the usual conical spin injectors. It is also simpler.

Comment: I'd guess the issue is that atomisation isn't the only goal, you also want good mixing between the propellants and high flow rates, neither of which misters are designed for

Comment: Another consideration is pressure drop. Those types of injectors work with large pressure drops.  When you anyways want the chamber at very high pressure, the required injection pressure may strain the structural and/or pump performance.

Comment: @AMcKelvy Where did you find that information that misters need pressure drops. I just keep finding that there are two types. Impeller and impinging misters. The impeller one is the one I am talking about. Impeller nozzles use a piston like object or other object to spin the water into a vortex before letting it escape from a small hole. Does the pressure drop lead to the atomization? Anyways, please provide a source I want to understand a bit better. Thank you